# Attainablility of Cramer Rao Bound with function of multi-parameters?

Tags: estimators, unbiased-estimator, cramer-rao

Suppose we have multivariables ${\boldsymbol  {\theta }}=\left[\theta _{1},\theta _{2},\dots ,\theta _{d}\right]^{T}\in {\mathbb  {R}}^{d}$, and we want to estimate the function of parameters $\boldsymbol \phi(\boldsymbol  {\theta })$ with unbiased estimator $\boldsymbol T(X)$, [CRB states that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%E2%80%93Rao_bound#Multivariate_case:%7E:text=.-,Multivariate%20case,-%5Bedit%20source) we have a lower bound as:
$${\displaystyle \operatorname {cov} _{\boldsymbol {\theta }}\left({\boldsymbol {T}}(X)\right)\geq \boldsymbol\phi (\theta )^TI\left({\boldsymbol {\theta }}\right)^{-1}\boldsymbol\phi (\theta )}$$
where $I(\boldsymbol \theta)$ is the fisher information matrix. I wonder what's the attainability of this bound, I find the bound in [Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%E2%80%93Rao_bound#Multivariate_case:%7E:text=.-,Multivariate%20case,-%5Bedit%20source) but I can't find the attainability in the wekipedia link. Is this bound always attainable?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under some conditions, the Cramer-Rao bound is attained if and only if we deal with an exponential family.

See e.g.

> Lehmann, E. L. (1983). Theory of Point Estimation. Springer-Verlag,
> New York. p.123

or

> Shao, Jun. Mathematical statistics. Springer Science & Business Media,
> 2003. p.171

Comment: Thank you very much, but why I see in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation#Efficiency) that the bound is always attainable by maximum likelihood estimator asymptotically?

Comment: @narip The statement in Wikipedia is about asymptotics, $n\to\infty$, but the attainability theorem I cited above is for finite $n$.